# Azure DevOps Get Analytic-View with C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I try to get these data in a c# client:

[image]

These data are created through the website and edited via Power Bi.

Lib i try to use:
https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client

Try to start like this way:

```cs
var settings = new ODataClientSettings("http://myServer/tfs/myOrg/myTeam/_odata/V3.0/", 
new NetworkCredential("myName", "myPw", "myDomain"));
var client = new ODataClient(settings);
```

I can´t find a way to call these view inside my code.
Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried different libs to get these information.
But found no solution to get what i want.